# how to skip update shopping cart option in magento?

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and i am using `Magento Ver. 1.6.1.0 - Custom Beta`. My client ask me to skip update shopping cart step (`http://mydomain.com/checkout/cart/`) and go directly to checkout page(`https://mydomain.com/onestepcheckout/`) .That is when a user clicks on `BUY NOW` button it should directly go to checkout page rather than updating shopping cart. How can i do this? Is there any options available in admin panel or should i edit the code if it is so where can i find the BUY NOW action. Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why are you using a beta version? Version 1.6.1.0 has an official version, as does 1.6.2.0.

Its generally a bad idea to skip the Cart phase, as users have come to expect it. However, if you really want to, you can override the `addAction` function in the `CartController` of the `Mage/Checkout` module. This is located in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`. For more instructions on overriding controllers, [read this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller). You'll want to keep most of the code in the `addAction` function the same, just change the redirects at the end to go to `Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')`.